# SpecFlow API automation tests running slowly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance, automated-tests, specflow

I am running circa 500 API automation tests using SpecFlow with CSharp (and Visual Studio).

Sometimes the API tests run very rapidly (taking the expected few seconds to run).  However, other times some of them will randomly hang and take 10 minutes or longer to run.  I have looked at the 'Output' pane and selected 'Tests', but nothing shows up while the tests are hanging.  Can anyone recommend a good way of debugging these hanging tests?

Note: I do not have any 'wait' aspects in my tests except 'await' for the API responses.

Comment: You will need to profile the tests. Looking at the test results, are their particular steps that seem to take longer? How long does each API call take when the tests are running slowly? What times of day are you running those tests?

Answer (score 1):

After using Fiddler to debug the issue, I noticed the API requests were never being sent.  Turned out it was accessing the Database in the test setup that was causing the issue.  I was returning all values in a table and then filtering, rather than requesting a filtered set of data.  Oops! Hope this response saves someone else some time in the future. If slow tests, debug line by line and work out the exact section that is slowing things down.

Comment: This is the key. Performance issues never seem to occur where you think they should. Always measure first. I had a Selenium/SpecFlow test suite that was running slow. I thought it was starting the browser before each test. Only after measuring did I realize we incurred a 7 second pause to delete files from an upload folder before each test, because we left old directories laying around instead of deleting them when they were empty. Always, always, always measure first.

Comment: @Charlie Seligman ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as the answer to change its status to Answered.